# How can I programatically set the roll back point for a transaction in spring?

Tags: java, sql, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

How can I specify the rollback point for a transaction in Spring?

Assuming the following scenario, I have to perform a really long insert into the db which takes quite some times (several minutes). This insert operation is wrapped in a transaction which ensures that if a problem occurs, the transaction is aborted and the database is restored to the status preceding the beginning of the transaction.

However, this solution affects the performance of the application since other transactions cannot access the db while the long transaction is being executed. I solved this issue by splitting the large transaction in several smaller transactions that perform the same operation. However, if one of these small transactions fails, the database rolls back to the status preceding this last transaction. Unfortunately, this would leave the database in an incorrect status. I want that if an errors occurs in any of these smaller transactions, the database rolls back to the status before the first small transaction ( i.e. exactly the same status, it would roll back if this operation is performed by a singular transaction).

Do you have any suggestion how I can achieve this using Spring transactions?

Comment: Staging tables might help you with this.

Comment: Yes, this is another solution. A similar problem arises when moving data from staging tables to the production tables if the data into the stages tables is rather big.

Comment: Scheduling this to happen when things are not busy might be an option.

Comment: Yes, that's an option. Unfortunately, I don't control when this operation is triggered. An administrator kicks it off, I can just recommend to run it when the server is not too busy.

Comment: I am not sure Spring (or any other framework for that matter) would help you here. It's really about how you can change your code so that the transaction duration is as short as it can be. A temporary table might be an option. A refactoring of the code may be another.

Comment: What did the Administrator say when you said that making this a scheduled job would reduce his workload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look to http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/TransactionStatus.html . 
It has required functionality:
- create savepoint
- release savepoint
- rollback to savepoint

Of course, your transaction manager (and underlying JDBC driver, and DB) should support the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use same primary key sequence for staging tables and production tables then you shall batch moving data from stg to prod. when a small transaction fails you can use the keys in staging table to delete from production table. that way you can restore production table to its original state